# Errors in Oculus Controller Movement Configuration Scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, virtual-reality, oculus

We are working on a VR Driving project using Oculus controllers. We are stuck on a bit wherein we are tryin to move the car forward and backward using the controllers. The camera view is set to be inside the car, but when we try to move the car faster, the camera view moves out of the car.

In addition to this, when we turn left or right and try to move forward, the car seems to move sideways but not in the direction to which we turn towards. Kindly help us on wit this issue.

The Unity version that in use is 2021.3.11

we wanted the player to drive the car smoothly but as soon as the speed is increased the camera tends to jump out of the car.

Comment: We need some more info on this. What have you tried and how it works now, which doesn't produce the intended outcome? Unity setup and/or code would help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.